# Получить название страны и города по широте и долготе (Google Maps API)

Tags: google-maps-api, карты

Как при помощи Google Maps API узнать название страны и города по широте и долготе?

Comment: А чем парсить собираетесь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Геокодирование – процесс преобразования адресов (например, "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") в географические координаты (например, широта 37,423021 и долгота -122,083739), которые можно использовать для размещения маркеров на карте или ее позиционирования.

Обратное геокодирование – это процесс преобразования географических координат в адреса, понятные для пользователя. Представленная в Google Maps Geocoding API служба обратного геокодирования также позволяет найти адрес по указанному идентификатору места.

Google Maps Geocoding API обеспечивает непосредственный доступ к этим службам через запрос HTTP. В следующем примере служба Geocoding используется через Google Maps JavaScript API для демонстрации основных возможностей.

Запрос Google Maps Geocoding API имеет следующий вид:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/outputFormat?parameters
```

где `outputFormat` может принимать одно из следующих значений:

json (рекомендуется) – задает вывод в формате JavaScript Object Notation (JSON);
 либо xml – задает вывод в формате XML.
Для доступа к Google Maps Geocoding API через HTTP используйте следующий формат:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/outputFormat?parameters
```

Пример для Вас:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Боле подробную информацию можно узнать здесь:  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=ru#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: В этом списке https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=ru#Types какой вариант наиболее подходит для  получения названия города